# g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command, works from bin directory

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

When I use it with `c:\mingw\bin\gcc` it works but when I try to run it from some other directory it doesn't. I'v set the environment variable path to:

> c:\mingw\bin;

I am using windows 10.

Comment: You need to add the directory to the `PATH`.

Comment: I already have:
http://i.imgur.com/GJWjagQ.png

Comment: Changing that setting used to require a restart, have you tried that? Or maybe just use the `path` command? Like in `path %PATH%;C:\mingw\bin`

Comment: Yeah that works but i dont know why setting the environment variable isnt. Iv tried restarting.

Comment: Perhaps something else is wrong with the path.  I see you've included "C:MinGW" in the path - without the \ after the C:  (should not cause a problem but you never know). A bad path spec, however, could cause your issue.